# comparing numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to classify some data based on euclidean distances in matlab the only problem is that matlab is giving me numbers that look like these as distances

```
0 + 4.9713i
0 + 7.8858i

 num1<num2  
 num2<num1
```

both return 0. how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you're getting are imaginary numbers. You should never obtain imaginary numbers when you calculate Euclidean distances.

Check that your Euclidean distances are correct, such as

`distance=sqrt(deltaX.^2 + deltaY.^2)`

If you're really sure that your distances should be complex numbers, make the comparison using e.g. the norm, i.e.

`norm(num2) > norm(num1)`

This evaluates to `true` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with real and imaginary parts are not orderable.  Maybe you mean order by distance from origin?